# What is the meaning of main_syntax

Tags: vim

I'm writing a vim syntax file.
And I found a variable called `main_syntax` is used in several existing syntax files.
But I can't find any documentation explaining it.

This [document](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_44.html#44.12) only describes another variable, `b:current_syntax`, which is
used to tell another script what the current syntax is.

Looks like `main_syntax` has the same meaning.
Is it a legacy variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some syntax scripts support being imported into another syntax via `:syntax include`, e.g. *javascript* inside *html*.

The `main_syntax` variable keeps track which syntax was actually set by the user / filetype; included syntax scripts then omit the clearing of existing syntax items when this variable is set. (Whereas syntax scripts are supposed to `:finish` without any actions if `b:current_syntax` is set.) Another difference to `b:current_syntax` is that `main_syntax` is only defined during the actual syntax loading process, whereas the other persists.

TL;DR: If you support including / include other syntaxes yourself, copy the conditional boilerplate from an existing syntax, e.g. `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim`; if not, you can ignore this.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a convention of a vim supported concept.  If the latter, how did you find docs on it?

Comment: @DanielKaplan: There's no explicit documentation, but several syntaxes that ship with Vim use `main_syntax`. As most syntax authors base their syntaxes on those, it's a strong convention, and probably also supported by Bram. If you think this should be documented, please submit a doc patch!